# Can't update jsf component from p:commandLink in jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, modal-dialog, commandlink

I'm using jsf p:commandLink from jQuery modal dialog. It calls an actionListener but can't update components. If I work the same button integrated within the page, it works fine. Is there any idea what should I check and how to find a problem?

```
<p:commandLink id="connectComp" value="connect" styleClass="iconConnect"
               actionListener="#{comprecommend.connectCompetence}"
               update="compRecommendGrowl :changableActivitiesRegion :RecommendedCompetencesPanel"
               oncomplete="$('#accessCompetenceHereBallon .ballonMessage').trigger('pulsate');">
    <f:param name="compUri" value="#{compIterator.uri}" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: Are you using PrimeFaces modal dialog or custom jQuery modal dialog?

Comment: Are you trying any example in Primefaces or you using native jquery modal window?

Comment: I'm using a native jquery modal dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after I removed the h:body elements that were in included components. I realized that the structure of the generated html page contained multiple body tags which probably caused that modal dialog was attached to the random body tag.